# How to retrieve value from DropDownList in List View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm trying to retrieve the value in my dropdownlist that is in my list View.
This is my dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSize" runat="server" CssClass="ddl" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="S">Small +RM5.00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="M">Medium +RM10.00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="L">Large +RM15.00</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="X">Xtra-Large +RM20.00</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the current way which I used to retrieve the value of my dropdownlist.

```
protected void prodList_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
                size = (e.Item.FindControl("ddlSize") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
        }
```

By using the method above and got an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object which means im passing a null value.

Comment: Pull out `e.Item.FindControl("ddlSize")` separate and assign it to a var, set a breakpoint, what is it when you assign it, is it null or does it contain a value?

Comment: Does your `ListViewItem` contain this `DropDownList`? `e.Item` should return a `ListviewItem`, then you are trying to find a `DropDownList` *inside* that `ListViewItem`...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ sorry for not understanding but what do you mean by seperate?

Comment: `size = (e.Item.FindControl("ddlSize") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;` instead of that do `var size = e.Item;`, set a breakpoint on that, then step through your code and what is `size`, is it null or is it something? It should be a `ListViewItem` according to your post.

Comment: yeah the `DropDownList` is inside of the `ListViewItem`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I tried using the breakpoint seems like it did not go through the event `OnItemCommand`

Comment: `seems like it did not go through the event`, if that is the case can you explain this error then: `got an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object` according to your post?

Comment: `Session["prodID"] = lblprodId.Text;
            Session["prodSize"] = size;
            Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");` I'm trying to save the size into the `session` and display it on the other page by retrieving the size from the `session` which contain null value.

Answer (score 0):

According to the article, OnItemCommand is only triggered if you have a button inside your ListView Control clicked, are you sure that you had the button already, if yes, I think it should work because I've replicated your issue on my machine?

[Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry to ask what is the difference between link button and button. Because I'm currently using button

Comment: There is no different I think

Comment: yeah i put it in a different button thats why it doesn't work. But right now i have another problem with retrieving the value from a modal popup T.T